# React-Native:Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {pname})

Tags: react-native

Actually I developing Sample appilication,I want to displayed list of names using map function in react native menu option:

**first i was declare one array:**

after next i wrote map function in render() and that component used in return() at menu context Component.

```
    var ListNames = [{"pname":"Smith"},{"pname":"Jhon"},{"pname":"Steve"},{"pname":"Ferr"},{"pname":"Kevin"}];

    render(){

      ListNames.map((ele, i)=>{
                         <Text>{ele.pname}</Text>           
      })

    return(
     <MenuContext style={{height:50,marginTop:20}} ref="MenuContext">
                    <Menu style={styles.dropdown} onSelect={(value) => this.setState({ dropdownSelection: value })}>
                     <MenuTrigger style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}> 
                     <View style={{flex:.7}}>
                       <Text style={{color:'black',fontSize:15}}>{this.state.dropdownSelection}</Text> 
                       </View>

                       <View style={{flex:.3,alignItems:'flex-end'}}>           
                       <Image source = {require('./../images/dropdown.png')} style={{height:15,width:20,marginTop:3}}/>
                      </View>
                      </MenuTrigger>
                     <MenuOptions optionsContainerStyle={styles.dropdownOptions1}
                                  renderOptionsContainer={(options) => <ScrollView><Text>SELECT....</Text>{options}</ScrollView>}>


                       <MenuOption value={ListNames}>
                         **{ListNames}**
                       </MenuOption>


                      {/* <MenuOption value="Kevin">
                         <Text>Kevin</Text>
                       </MenuOption>
                       <MenuOption value="Pieterson">
                         <Text>Pieterson</Text>
                       </MenuOption>
                       <MenuOption value="David">
                         <Text>David</Text>
                       </MenuOption>
                       <MenuOption value="Meissi">
                         <Text>Meissi</Text>
                       </MenuOption> */}
                     </MenuOptions>
                   </Menu>
                  </MenuContext>)
}
```

So I want using Mapping Function in react native menu option module is it Displaying are names using map function

any one please suggest this

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Solved this , i am Very Foolish thinking, just  in retturn methode

```
<MenuOption value={ListNames>
                                     {ListNames}
                                   </MenuOption>
```

replaced to given below

```
 {
                      this.state.ListNames.map((ele, i)=>{
                        return <MenuOption value={ele.playerName}>
                                 <Text>{ele.playerName}</Text>
                               </MenuOption>           
                      })
                    }
```